# Mac Terminal Git not working after installing certificates

Tags: ios, xcode, git

I cant use mac terminal to work with git commands or pod commands.H think this problem was found after I install push notification certificate files. I get this error when I run git install clone or other git and pod commands

```
xcrun: error: unable to load libxcrun (dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/lib/libxcrun.dylib, 5): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/lib/libxcrun.dylib: code signing blocked mmap() of '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/lib/libxcrun.dylib').
```

Comment: Looks like you should reinstall Xcode.

Comment: @trojanfoe I did it but not work

Comment: someone have an answer please ?